# g++ include path being ignored?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, g++

I am trying to compile files with a directory structure like this:

```
|
|--- src (C files)
      |
      |---- include (header files)
```

I a compiling the C files as C++ (so I can more easily use library in C++ apps, without using `extern C` CCV etc).

This is my g++ command:

> g++ -I$(pwd)/include *.c  -o ../build/foo

When I run this, I get the following error:

> file1.c:77:10: fatal error: setup.h: No such file or directory

#### file1.c

```
#include "stdio.h"
...
#include "setup.h"   <- Line 77
```

Why is the `I` flag being ignored (apparently) by g++ ?  Note, I do not have the authority to modify the *.c files.

Comment: Have you checked that the value of `$(pwd)` is the folder that contains the subfolder `include`?

Comment: @MatG Goes without saying, it was the first thing I checked.

Comment: `$(pwd)` executes a command, how about `${PWD}` or even just `-Iinclude` (the current directory should be implied)

Comment: Can you show full unedited output of `ls include/setup.h && g++ -Iinclude *.c -o ../build/foo`.